# WPF Popup control has black background. allowTransparency doesnt work

Tags: popup, wpf-controls, transparency

I have **WPF popup control** that needs to have transparent background. I set **AllowsTransparency="True"** but it isn't applied. This is on a desktop application. Applying allowsTransparency from code behind doesn't help also, it actually sets it to false. Does anyone have solution about this? Thanks!

The xaml:

```
<Popup Name="myPopup"
    StaysOpen="True"
    Placement="Right"
    MinWidth="100"
    MinHeight="100"
    Width="Auto"
    Height="Auto"
    PopupAnimation="Fade"
    **AllowsTransparency="True"**>

 <Border BorderThickness="0" 
    BorderBrush="{x:Static styles:Resources.myBorderBrush}" 
    Background="{StaticResource myBackground}"
    Effect="{StaticResource myShadowEffect}">
    <StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

verify that your application runs in full trust. According to [msdn page for Popup.AllowsTransparency property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.allowstransparency(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the AllowsTransparency property is set to true in an application that does not run in full trust, the AllowsTransparency property value is changed to false.